# How to click all the links one by one using protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, jasmine2.0

I have stored all the link elements in var as below-

```
it("should click all the links one by one", function() 
{
    browser.get("https://angularjs.org");
    var allLinks=element.all(by.tagName("a"));
    var number=allLinks.count();
    expect(number).toEqual(80);
})
```

This part is working fine, now I want to navigate to links stored in var allLinks one by one

Answer (score 2):

Protractor API provides [each](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) to iterate over ElementArrayFinder and iteract with the ElementFinder objects

> `element.all(locator).each(eachFunction)`
>
> Calls the input function on each ElementFinder represented by the
>   ElementArrayFinder.

You can do something like this

```
allLinks.each(function(link){
        link.click();
        //Do some validations you want to do on the new opened link
        browser.navigate().back();
    })
```